# Adding additional rewards on existing rewards when reward rates change

Tags: solidity

I am working on staking contract in Solidity, and what I want to do is to add rewards on user balance when rewards rate is changed. I have this following code and when I change rate from 1 to 10, on user balance I have 10 times more rewards, and next time I change rate from 10 to 1, balance is 10 times lower. Just want to add new rewards with different reward rate on existing rewards.

```
struct StakerData {
        uint256 totalStaked;
        uint256 lastStakedTimestamp;
        uint256 reward;
    }

mapping(address => StakerData) public stakers;

function calculateReward(address user) public view returns (uint256) {
        StakerData storage staker = stakers[user];
        uint256 stakingDuration = block.timestamp.sub(staker.lastStakedTimestamp);
        uint256 calculatedRewards = staker.totalStaked.mul(rewardRate).mul(stakingDuration).div(1e18);
        return calculatedRewards;
    } 
function setRewardRate(uint256 _rewardRate) public onlyOwner {
        rewardRate = _rewardRate;
    }
```

When new rate has been changed, it multiple with existing total staked balance without adding new rewards with different rate.